# Oracle APEX : How to fetch new value of switch column (in dynamic action - JavaScript) in Interactive Grid?

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

My Interactive Grid SQL Query's last column is of Switch Type with Values Yes / No. If user changes value of this column (from N to Y), I want to capture the new changed value (Y) in the dynamic action JavaScript in "val" but the below code snippet is returning the initial value of the switch column (N), not the changed value (Y).

```
var $te = $(this.triggeringElement);
var rowId = $te.closest('tr').data('id');
var ig$ = apex.region("GMIG").widget();
var model = ig$.interactiveGrid("getViews", "grid").model;
var record = model.getRecord(rowId);
var comm = model.getValue( record, "USER_EXIST");
var val = comm["v"];

alert(val);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is as simple as this:

```
val = $v(this.triggeringElement);
alert(val);
```

`$v` is an APEX function that is aware of the APEX controls and how to get their values.

Comment: Thank you Tony! It worked!!!

I have a followup query... how to set a value (Y / N) to a switch column in interactive grid? In the above example, if a user changes USER_EXIST from N to Y for a record, I want to fetch this new value (in "val") and update other records which are already selected by the user using ROW_SELECTOR. This is my ultimate goal. Am able to fetch the selected rows and everything, am not able to assign the "val" to selected rows. Can you please help?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the answer - I'd suggest to post a new question for this.